# AttributeError: module 'mediapipe' has no attribute 'solutions'

Tags: python, module, gpu, face-detection, mediapipe

I am running the media pipe face detection, when I run this binary given in media pipe documentation, I followed the same steps as given, but it's giving the following error.

AttributeError: module 'media pipe' has no attribute 'solutions'

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

# For webcam input:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(
    model_selection=0, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as 
face_detection:
  while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue

    # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not 
writeable to
    # pass by reference.
    image.flags.writeable = False
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = face_detection.process(image)

    # Draw the face detection annotations on the image.
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    if results.detections:
      for detection in results.detections:
        mp_drawing.draw_detection(image, detection)
    # Flip the image horizontally for a selfie-view display.
    cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Face Detection', cv2.flip(image, 1))
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
      break
cap.release()
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are running?

Comment: please post ```mediapipe``` and ```python``` versions